# set text using innerHTMl to relative id

Tags: javascript, html

i need to set the innerHtml  text to relative elements using id (spanid_comment)

Below is my HTMl

```
<div id="edit-comment-form_1">
   <p>dfdfdfdfdf</p>
   <p id="spanid_comment" ></p>
</div>
```

Below is Javascript i tried

```
 document.getElementById("#edit-comment-form_1 #spanid_comment").innerHTML = "boss";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can check this answer

```
var selectedPageHtml = document.getElementById("edit-comment-form_1");
selectedPageHtml.querySelector("#spanid_comment").innerHTML = "boss";
```

Comment: negative vote :tell me is my code was wrong i will remove it

Answer (score 1):

What you want only works with [`.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) (or [`.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) if you know you're going to have multiple).

```js
document.querySelector("#edit-comment-form_1 #spanid_comment").innerHTML = "boss";
```

```html
<div id="edit-comment-form_1">
  <p>dfdfdfdfdf</p>
  <p id="spanid_comment"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: If you know you're going to have multiple instances of the same id, you're doing something wrong. Ids are meant to be unique: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id

Comment: @madukp np. Accept the answer if it worked for you to let others know that as wel

Comment: and how to pass value to `function my_func(commentId, editCommentId) {

        document.querySelector(editCommentId commentId).innerHTML = "hii";
    }` ??  error is Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Comment: You really don't need #edit-comment-form_1, since #spanid_comment has to be unique.

Comment: #spanid_comment is not unique it is always  constant and only this edit-comment-form_1 or 2 or 3 unique

Comment: @madukp if #spanid_comment  constant then check my answer and youk can use fun and pass editCommentId var

Answer (score 0):

```
document.querySelector("#edit-comment-form_1 #spanid_comment").innerHTML = "boss";
```

Comment: i needed as nested

Comment: same answer is available